# why we need dummy subjects and it's usage?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, adverbs, dummy-pronouns

1. There is a book on the table -- existential clause
2. A book is on the table -- basic version
3. A book is there -- (there= on the table, adverb of place)
   An existential clause is a clause that refers to the existence or presence of something. If something exists in some place then we use adverbs of place. So adverbs can fulfill the use of existence or presence of something. Then why we need dummy subjects and its usage?
4. A book is there ~ There is a book.
   If we point out that thing (here "the book") and tell that " There is a book", here "there" is not used as dummy subject but it is an adverb. The normal word order in positive sentence is “A book is there” (subject-verb-other components) but here “adverb-verb-subject”. Can we use this order? And which order is the best to use and why?

Comment: Existential "there" is a dummy pronoun where it typically occurs as subject (_There is a book on the table_). Locative "there" is an intransitive preposition which can occur in inversions (_There is my book_) or as a complement (_My book is there_.)

Comment: Here is my question. If something exists in some place then we use adverbs of place. So adverbs can fulfill the use of existence or presence of something. Then why we need dummy subjects and its usage?

Comment: No, existential "there" is not an adverb, but a dummy pronoun. Clauses require a subject, and existential "there" fills that syntactic role. Cf. "There is a sheep there" where the first "there" is subject and the second is locative complement.

Comment: Okay but what about the sentence "There is a sheep"? Here "there" is dummy subject or adverb?

Comment: It could be either in that example, depending on whether "there" is intended to denote the existence of the sheep or its location.

Comment: There is a sheep and A sheep is there. Here in two cases " there" is adverb of place. Am I right?

Comment: Read my last message which deals with that point.

Comment: If we point out of something there in that place it means the existence of something then we use adverb of place only right?

Comment: John and Mary are searching a sheep. John: Mary, where is the sheep? Mary: Look, there is the sheep.

Comment: A book is there ~ There is a book. If we point out that thing (here "the book") and tell that " There is a book", here "there" is not used as dummy subject but it is an adverb. The normal word order in positive sentence is “A book is there” (subject-verb-other components) but here “adverb-verb-subject”. Can we use this order? And which order is the best to use and why?

Comment: @BillJ: Why can't **a sheep** be the required subject in the clause **There is a sheep eating grass over there**? Treating **there** in existential constructions as a dummy pronoun seems perverse and makes no sense to me. If you defend the view by saying "Ah, but there is a good reason to think of it that way", does the alleged pronoun **there** refer to the  noun phrase "a good reason"? In **here's something to consider** do you consider **here** a dummy pronoun?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo The strong grounds for saying 'there' is the subject are that it undergoes subject-auxiliary inversion "is there a sheep..?" and it can be the subject in a question-tag "there's a sheep.., *isn't there*?. I believe it's not wrong to say 'sheep' is the logical subject but 'there' is indeed the syntactic subject.

Comment: @user178049: But being the syntactic subject doesn't necessarily make the word **there** a pronoun.  *Cold is the best way to serve this soup.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo  Central pronouns are either diectic or anaphoric. But a dummy subject is different in that it doesn't have any of these properties. But we still analyze it as a pronoun because it passes the *question-tag test*. Afaik, only a pronoun can be a subject of a question-tag.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understand.  I don't think it's necessarily a dummy subject; I think it's an inversion or, at least, in its original sense, it was probably an inversion:

"There is the book!" (at that place is the book)

"Here is the book!" (at this place is the book)

"There are three people here." (This is perhaps a dummy subject)

I'm assuming the dummy subject that you're talking about is just an idiomatic expression that's been around so long in English that no one questions it; it's probably from a time in English when "there" could be used to mean "here" as well. In fact, in spoken French, "là" means "there" and "ici" mean "here"; however, one usually uses "là" for both "there" and "here" and "ici" is reserved more so to point to one thing that is closer if one should be discussing two different things.  I'm sure it runs along that kind of logic.  The French idiom for "there is/are" is "Il y a", which literally means "it there has" or "it has there" (yes "y" can mean "there" as well).

Some idioms just exist and that's the reason.  There was a lot of inversion in Old and Middle English, so that might be the reason that this "idiom" exists.  Have you ever wondered why it is technically "It is I" instead of "It's me"?  Well, in Middle English, the inversion was "It am I" and it slowly started being misconstrued as people thought the subject was "It" when really it was an inversion and the subject was "I".  After this, many people didn't like seeing a nominative pronoun in the predicate when, normally in English, there is an accusative pronoun, so this disjunctive formation using "me" came about; thus, we have "It's me" as the colloquial form of the very formal "It is I".

I hope that might have helped you out.  Take care and good luck.

Comment: Please stick to the topic of this thread which is about the contrast between existential and locative "there".